# Why is the Where clause in this LINQ Query not appending?

Tags: linq

```
IQueryable<Order> OrderQuery = db.Orders;

if (date_conditions != null)
{
    OrderQuery.Where(o => o.CreatedOn >= start_date);
    OrderQuery.Where(o => o.CreatedOn <= end_date);
}
return OrderQuery.ToList();
```

When I check the SQL query generated, there is no WHERE clause though the if condition is executed.
What am I doing wrong?

But, when I write the code,

```
db.Orders.Where(...)
```

all in one shot, it works

Comment: `Where` doesn't alter the collection in place, it just returns a filtered collection based on the collection passed in. You have to re-assign each time: `OrderQuery = OrderQuery.Where( ... );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign it to your query every time. The extensions method returns a new `IQuerable` every time essentially making your two calls to `Where` create a new `IQueryable` discarded it (since it is never assigned to a variable).

```
IQueryable<Order> OrderQuery = db.Orders;

var date_conditions = payload["date"];
if (date_conditions != null)
{
    var dates = date_conditions as DateTime?[];
    OrderQuery = OrderQuery.Where(o => o.CreatedOn >= dates[0]);
    OrderQuery = OrderQuery.Where(o => o.CreatedOn <= dates[1]);
}
return OrderQuery.ToList();
```